# TikZ / pgfmath: dim is now issuing something else

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

At my TikZ (TeXLive 2020)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathprint{dim("gas")}, \pgfmathprint{dim("abcd")}, 
\pgfmathprint{dim("abcdefg")}
\end{document}
```

gives out `3, 4, 7`;  with other words the numbers of letters between `"..."`

I was told that *the latest pgf version* outputs something else (1 or something).

What am I doing now? 
I need a function that counts the number of letters. And I need that within `pgfmath`, not somehow in general with plain TeX or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dim` function is meant for working out the dimension of a (comma-separated) array: these are all of dimension 1. Thus the older behaviour is a bug, not a feature.

We can add a new function that is explicitly for this job: I've called it `tokencnt`:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{tokencnt}{1}
  {
    \edef \pgfmathresult { \tl_count:n {#1} }
  }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\pgfmathprint{tokencnt("gas")}, \pgfmathprint{tokencnt("abcd")}, 
\pgfmathprint{tokencnt("abcdefg")}
\end{document}
```

(I've used `expl3` to do the real work here, as there is a pre-built function for doing token-counting. We could of course write that out manually ...)